# Error appearing when building cordova application with gradle

Tags: java, cordova, gradle

[image: error I'm getting on Cordova Build]

here's my gradle and JAVA Version

C:\Users\caola\OneDrive\Desktop\tester>gradle -v

---

### Gradle 8.3

Build time:   2023-08-17 07:06:47 UTC
Revision:     8afbf24b469158b714b36e84c6f4d4976c86fcd5

Kotlin:       1.9.0
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          20 (Oracle Corporation 20+36-2344)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64

C:\Users\caola\OneDrive\Desktop\tester>

Any Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that you are using Gradle 7.6 and this is not compatible with the Java version you are using. Your project should have Gradle wrapper files that specify the Gradle version used. As shown below this is 7.6 and it is not compatible with the Java version you are using. The Gradle [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html?_ga=2.159681849.56212591.1709565268-2140149823.1709565268&_gl=1*10fo7k0*_ga*MjE0MDE0OTgyMy4xNzA5NTY1MjY4*_ga_7W7NC6YNPT*MTcwOTU2NTI3MC4xLjEuMTcwOTU2NTMwNC4yNi4wLjA.) shows that 7.6 is compatible with Java 19.

[image]

Downgrading the Java version to Java 19 or upgrading Gradle should fix this issue.